# Text wrap and save txt file using PHP

Tags: php, sed, explode, word-wrap

I want to wrap a text and save to txt file.
For example text is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.

I want to wrap text every 40 words and save a txt file.

So first txt file:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

And second txt file:

> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait

Will be like that.

I tried this code but I couldn't figure out wrap.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
 nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et.";
$word = explode(" ",$text);
$count = count($word);
$limit = 40;
if($count <= $limit) { $cut = $count*50/100; }
else { $cut = $limit; }
for($i = 0; $i <= $cut; $i++)
{ $text1= $word[$i].' ' ; echo $text1;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using file_put_contents() you store a text into text(.txt) file
Refer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

As i.e :

```
$file   = "/folder_path/name_of_file.txt";
file_put_contents($file, print_r($_GET['data'], true), FILE_APPEND);
```

and you must give permission to folder where you want to store your text file.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i cant figure how automaticly generate file name. For example; text lenght is 4000 character and wrap 10 times. How to save file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt ..... ?

Comment: you want to set name of file dynamically 
As i.e : $name = rand()."specific_name.txt";//this is just example 
$file   = "/folder_path/".$name;
it will give you output dynamically. you will do it on your own way to generate name

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the `wordwrap` function. This function will break the string in every X characters, inserting an character to divide.

For example, in this code, i want to break the string in every 20 characters:

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "\n");
```

The return will be:

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
```

So every part divided on the string is separeted by `\n`. Now you can use `explode` to get the parts of the string into an array

```
$newtext = explode("\n", $newtext);
```

This will be my array with the broken string:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(19) "The quick brown fox"
  [1] =>
  string(20) "jumped over the lazy"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "dog."
}
```

And to save the file you can see this tutorial:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$charnum="100";
$number=strlen($text);
$tekrar=$number/$charnum;
$newtext= str_replace("\n", "", $text);
$newtext = wordwrap($newtext, $charnum, "\n");
$newtext = explode("\n", $newtext);

for ( $count=1 ; $count < $tekrar ; $count++ )
{

$file   = "/files/$count.txt";
file_put_contents($file,$newtext[$count]);
```

I write like that but this time i take that warning:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/files/1.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```